# Elliptic curve point addition clarification

Tags: public-key

In a book I am reading currently, it asks to perform the addition of $(2,7)$ and $(5,2)$ in the elliptic curve defined as $y^2=x^3+2x+2 \mod 17$.

Now, I believe this is impossible, as these points are not part of the group, hence it is not possible to compute the third point. Is that correct?

Pretty sure I am correct, but just would like clarification that i'm not making a huge mistake, as this book has not had any errors so far so I'm suprised to see one.

Comment: @Squeamish makes a point. If it's possible, we'd like to know in what context was the off-curve point given in the book, as it might be a mind exercise aimed to show the importance of validating curve points.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you naively plug those numbers into the addition formula?  Anything obviously untoward?

This may be an exercise in the impact of invalid-curve attacks.